# How to use @html.hiddenfor() two view in MVC - one for getting data from database and other to store data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

fist model get the list of questions.

but i am not able to access them while using @Html.HiddenFor() etc

these item are visible if i use @Html.Hidden() or anything without ....For method...

any idea how can i do this

here are my classes

```
   public class QuestionModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string QuestDes { get; set; }
    public int Aspect { get; set; }
}

 public class AnswerModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string SelectedAns { get; set; }
        public virtual QuestionModel Question { get; set; }
        public virtual PersonModel Person { get; set; }
    }
```

my controller code

```
public ActionResult GPage2()
        {
       var tview = new Tuple<List<QuestionModel>,AnswerModel>(getQuestions(),new AnswerModel());


            return View(tview);

        }
private List<QuestionModel> getQuestions()
        {
            var qList = (from q in dbcon.Questions
                         orderby q.Id
                         select q).ToList();
            return qList;

        }
```

in cshtml page

```
@model Tuple<List<QuestionModel>,AnswerModel>

  <td> @Html.Label(Model.Item2.SelectedAns)</td>
@Html.LabelFor(.......................) not working
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what you have posted you need to use a view model that includes your 2 models

```
public class ViewModel{
    public List<QuestionModel> Questions { get; set; }
    public List<AnswerModel> Answers { get; set; }
}
```

then on your view

```
@model ViewModel
```

using this setup your for helpers should work.  since it is a list putting them in a foreach would look something like this.

```
@foreach(var temp in Model.Questions){
    @Html.LabelFor(x => temp.Aspect) 
    //etc
}
```